# Directly capturing cin to a function as parameter without a temporary variable

Tags: c++, cin

More of a curiosity question than anything else,
but is it actually possible to pass whatever goes
through `std::cin` to a function as a parameter without
defining an temporary variable just for reading from input?

Instead of using an extra temporary variable:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string time; // extra define temporary variable for input 
// now 2 lines follow with separate operations
cin >> time; // 1) input to "time"
in_time = get_minutes (time); // 2) put "time" to function as parameter
cin >> time;  // another extra line
wake_up = get_minutes (time);
cin >> time;  // and another other extra line ....
opens = get_minutes (time);
```

I want to directly use `std::cin` in a function parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

in_time = get_minutes (<use of cin here>);
wake_up = get_minutes (<use of cin here>);
opens = get_minutes (<use of cin here>);
```

Is this possible?

Comment: pass to where? waste a variable ??

Comment: You shouldnt worry about such things, as a good compiler should know when it can eliminate such variables.

Comment: Maybe better to pass cin itself to the function. But in general no, there is no way to use cin without variables since the compiler needs to know the type of the object you are trying to read, and it gets that from the type of the variable.

Comment: @john: "compiler needs to know the type of the object you are trying to read, and it gets that from the type of the variable" - except for `cin.get()` which always reads a character, and some less often useful functions like `peek()`.

Comment: @user1749737: Syntactically a template `T read<T>(cin)` will do the job, but it will be very dangerous, think of `f(read<int>(cin),read<string>(cin));` what comes first?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily define a wrapper function to do this.

```
template<class T>
T get(std::istream& is){
  T result;
  is >> result;
  return result;
}
```

Any decent compiler will use NRVO to eliminate the copy.

You can use it like this

```
f(get<int>(std::cin));
```

Make sure not to use it multiple times in one statement though. The order of the stream operations is unspecified if you do something like this.

```
f(get<int>(std::cin),get<int>(std::cin));
```

You could get the two ints in either order.

Answer (score 2):

`cin` is just a stream, it doesn't have any magic. You can use the other stream methods to do whatever you want.

Check out http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is negative. In order to input something through a stream, you will have to "waste" a variable. You cannot pass the input data directly to a function without an intermediate variable.

Comment: "You cannot pass the input data directly to a function without an intermediate variable." - you can in trivial cases - `f(cin.get());`.  The streaming operators that give iostreams their character definitely do require a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
f(*std::istream_iterator<T>(std::cin));
```

That’s probably not *simpler* than using a variable, though, and is undefined behavior if the stream fails to provide a `T`.